# Isogenies of Elliptic curves with complex multiplication

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

This is a slight continuation of a previous question of mine.

Given an elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ which has complex multiplication.

How would one find each $p$ such that $E$ admits a $p$-isogeny? Further more how would one construct such an isogenous curve?

Example: if one considers the Mordell equations $$
E: y^2=x^3+n.
$$

Then we see that $E$ has complex multiplication because of the endomorphism
\begin{align*}
E& \rightarrow E\\
(x,y) &\mapsto (\zeta x,y)
\end{align*} where $\zeta$ is a third root of unity. Can one find for any particular $n$ which $p$-isogeny arise?

Note: A suggestion that “In case the curve has CM. Then $E[p]$ for any prime of good reduction is fully described by cm theory. As in the above example over its cm field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ we have that $E[p]$ is a free rank 1 module over $\mathcal{O}_K/p$. Hence isogenies over Q can only occur for additive primes.”

If someone could expand this point and explain why it is true this would also be very helpful.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? What is the set of primes $p$ such that there is an isogeny $E \to E$ (i.e. an endomorphism) of degree $p$, defined over $\Bbb Q$ ?

Comment: Hi @Watson thanks for the reply! Yes, this is exactly what I am asking. I know that Mazur's theorem gives me all possible $p$ for which this can happen but I need to know given any particular $n$ what the exact set of primes are that give isogenies over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $p$. As mentioned above, someone mentioned that these are the primes for which the curve has additive reduction but I do not fully understand their reasoning behind it.

Comment: @Watson I thought an elliptic curve could acquire an isogeny if it gets a $p$-torsion point after some finite extension. So there is some $p$-torsion point (say $Q$) that is not defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ but is defined over some finite extension. Then if one considers the subgroup of $E[p]$ generated by $Q$, say $C=<Q>$, if $C$ is Galois invariant we can construct an isogeny $E \rightarrow E/C$. The quote is from another member of the Mathoveflow community but the member would rather stay anonymous.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395847

Comment: Ah, ok, so you are _not_ requiring the isogeny to land again in $E$ (then you above comment saying "this is exactly what I am asking" is wrong).

Comment: @Watson Yes, sorry I should of said $E \rightarrow E'$ where $E$ and $E'$ are isogenous over $\mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a prime $p$ is unramified in the CM field, $K$, then the mod $p$ image of the galois representation is equal to the normaliser of a cartan subgroup, hence not contained in a Borel subgroup (by the classification of maximal subgroups of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$) and thus $E$ cannot admit a $p$-isogeny (an elliptic curve $E/L$ admits a $p$-isogeny if and only if $\bar{\rho}_{E,p}(G_L)$ is contained in a Borel subgroup).

Now why is this the case that the image is contained in the normaliser of a Cartan subgroup? Note that the CM action $\mathcal{O} \to Aut(E[p])$ (defined over $K$) factors through $\mathcal{O}/p\mathcal{O}$. Then in particular the image of $G_K$ contains (in fact it is equal to) a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}/p\mathcal{O}$ (these are precisely the Cartan subgroups). But CM does not act on $Aut(E[p])$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, so $\bar{\rho}_{E,p}(G_{\mathbb{Q}})$ contains a Cartan subgroup as an index $2$ subgroup and is thus equal to its normaliser (by the classification of maximal subgroups of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$).

Thus $E$ may only admit a $p$-isogeny if $p$ is ramified in the CM field.

Comment: Really nice answer! Do you know where I can read more about when Elliptic curves display $p$-isogenies (both for CM and non-CM elliptic curves).

Comment: Well, the basics appear in Silverman Chapter III. When $p \neq char(k)$ the way to understand isogenies is via modular curves (specifically $X_0(p)$, this is what I'm thinking when I'm thinking 'Borel subgroup'). Rohrlich's article in Cornell-Silverman-Stevens is a good starting point, as is the appendix of Silverman's book on Elliptic Curves

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! They are much appreciated.